# EmberJS + EmberCLI Unit Test Helper Function Undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to get a test helper working using Ember CLI, but I always get `[functionName] is undefined`.  Here is my test, helper, as according to the [emberjs docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/):

```
`import Ember from "ember"`

acceptanceHelpers = ->
    Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper("performLogin", (app) ->
        visit "/login"

        fillIn("#username", "sampleusername")
        fillIn("#password", "samplepassword")

        click(".form-actions button:first")
        wait()
    )

`export default acceptanceHelpers`
```

And where I use it: **`login-test.coffee`**:

```
`import Ember from "ember"`
`import startApp from "../helpers/start-app"`
`import acceptanceHelpers from "../helpers/acceptance-helpers"`

App = null

module "Acceptance: Login",
    setup: ->
        App = startApp()

    teardown: ->
        Ember.run App, "destroy"

test "User is able to log in / transition to dashboard", ->
    performLogin()
    andThen ->
        equal(currentRouteName(), "dashboard")
```

But I get:

> ReferenceError: performLogin is not defined
>       at Object.module.setup (unhost/tests/acceptance/login-test.js:15:16)
>       at Object.Test.setup (http://`localhost`:4200/assets/test-support.js:1063:31)
>       at http://`localhost`:4200/assets/test-support.js:1168:10
>       at process (http://`localhost`:4200/assets/test-support.js:887:24)
>       at http:/`/localhost`:4200/assets/test-support.js:476:5

How can I configure my acceptance test to properly use defined test helpers in Ember CLI?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options here:

You can just make a plain helper function to use, if you want to import into each test file:

```
//acceptance-helpers.js
export function performLogin() {
  visit "/login"

  fillIn("#username", "sampleusername")
  fillIn("#password", "samplepassword")

  click(".form-actions button:first")
  //  wait()  <--- This wait is unnecessary, 'click' will cause a wait  
}
```

And then in the test:

```
//login-test.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
import { performLogin } from '../helpers/acceptance-helpers';

var App;
module("Acceptance: Login", {
  setup: function(){
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function(){
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test("User is able to log in / transition to dashboard", function(){
  performLogin();
  andThen(function(){
    equal(currentRouteName(), "dashboard");
  });
});
```

Making and using a registered helper:

```
//Easiest is to put in test-helper.js ... it must be evaled before injectTestHelpers is called in   startApp
Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper( 'performLogin', function ( app ) {
  visit "/login"

  fillIn("#username", "sampleusername")
  fillIn("#password", "samplepassword")

  click(".form-actions button:first")
  // wait()  <--- wait is again unnecessary
});
```

And then in the test:

```
//login-test.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from '../helpers/start-app';
//No need to import anything to get performLogin, it was registered 

var App;
module("Acceptance: Login", {
  setup: function(){
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown: function(){
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test("User is able to log in / transition to dashboard", function(){
  performLogin();
  andThen(function(){
    equal(currentRouteName(), "dashboard");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely jshint failing, you need to add `performLogin` to `tests/.jshintrc` to the `predef` array:

```
"predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "performLogin", // like this
    ...
```